# use keyword in Rebol vs use keyword in Red

Tags: rebol, red

I wanted to use "Use" in Red but it seems it is quite different from use in Rebol, looking into help:

In Red:

```
  >> help use
       cause-error     function!     Causes an immediate error throw, w...
```

In Rebol

```
    >> help use
    USAGE:
        USE words body

    DESCRIPTION:
         Defines words local to a block.
         USE is a native value.

    ARGUMENTS:
         words -- Local word(s) to the block (Type: block word)
         body -- Block to evaluate (Type: block)
    >>
```

Is there an equivalent of Use in Red (/local or function not enough) so as to have block scope and not just function scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> source use
USE is an unset! value, so source is not available.
```

**use** is not yet implemented. What you see is just a function where help is finding the string 'use' in 'cause-error'. That's a byproduct of the enhanced searching of help also in names, description and interface etc.

As long as there is no **use** you can always use an anonymous context / object e.g

```
>> context [
[        a: 1
[        set 'f does  [print a]
[    ]
== make object! [
    a: 1
]
>> f
1
>> a
*** Script Error: a has no value
*** Where: catch
*** Stack:
```